# Magento 2 admin url

Tags: magento2, admin

After reading some online guideline, I tried changing my Magento admin url.

I found it at Stores-->Configuration--> Advanced-->Admin base url.

I decided to change the admin url but didnt include the "/". Now my admin urls(both old and new) returns a "404 NOT FOUND" page.

Already tried using ssh commands but to no effect including:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="magento".
```

I need help correcting this error. My current magento version is 2.1.9

Comment: Did you clear cache after Changing it? If you did and still not working, check in core_config_data table and try to change that field value. Hope you know how to find the value in the table and replace it.

Comment: Yes i did clear the cache. What field value am I to change in the core_config_data table as i do not see anything similar

Comment: I don't think Magento 2 stores this information in the database but for sure it can be found in `app/etc/env.php`

Answer (score 0):

Open file `app/etc/env.php` and change that:

```
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
```

After that run these commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I tried that still getting the same error page

Comment: what does it say in that file?

Comment: Try to run this command to see if the changes reflect: `php bin/magento info:adminuri`

Comment: the changes reflect

Comment: Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` from Magento root